# The images don't appear when using hover

Tags: html, css, image

I'm trying to get an image to change to another when i hover over the image, but nothing appears on screen and I'm baffled. The HTML and CSS are in the same file. everything is in a folder called 'walrus' and within that folder are the html/css coding and an image floder called 'images'.
Here's the code:

```
<style>
.b-george {
   width: 130px;
   height: 195px;
   background: url("images/beatlegeorge.jpg") no-repeat;
   margin: 50px;
}
.b-george:hover {
   background: url("images/george.jpg") no-repeat;
}
</style>
<div class="b-george"></div>'
```

Comment: nothing appear or not change ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide `background-size` value for that element:

```
background-size: 130px 195px;
```

```css
.b-george {
  width: 130px;
  height: 195px;
  background: url("https://www.netclipart.com/pp/m/1-15005_animals-clipart-png-cartoon-animals-png-cute-animal.png") no-repeat;
  margin: 50px;
  background-size: 130px 195px;
}
.b-george:hover {
  background: url("http://pluspng.com/img-png/animal-png-i-absolutely-love-tigers-and-have-two-of-my-own-on-my-tattoos-347.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-size: 130px 195px;
}
```

```html
<div class="b-george"></div>
```